# Why is my Ubuntu Core 14.04 system booting so slow?

Tags: linux, performance, ubuntu, ram, boot

Why is my Ubuntu Core 14.04 system booting so slow? After using the RAM_booster script an booting into ram my system is booting slower. It hangs between 2.71 and 13.48 seconds.

Here is a snipped of my boot log.

```
[    2.221962] usb 3-2.7: new low-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    2.244217] usb 3-2.7: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c063
[    2.244277] usb 3-2.7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.244322] usb 3-2.7: Product: DELL USB Laser Mouse
[    2.244354] usb 3-2.7: Manufacturer: DELL
[    2.244532] usb 3-2.7: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[    2.718291] Switched to clocksource tsc
[   13.480246] PM: Hibernation image not present or could not be loaded.
[   13.480498] Freeing unused kernel memory: 876K (c19bb000 - c1a96000)
[   13.480633] Write protecting the kernel text: 6552k
[   13.480750] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 2768k
[   13.480796] NX-protecting the kernel data: 5736k
[   13.496441] systemd-udevd[147]: starting version 204
```

Has someone any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

> Has someone any idea what the problem could be?

Yes. You're trying to use `RAM_booster` which promises nothing more than packing all your system into a squashfs image and loading that into RAM, so that instead of from your hard drive, things (applications, data) would always be loaded from RAM.

However, your boot process is exactly the point where that squashfs image is loaded from disk to RAM; now, instead of a normal boot, where only the things you'd actually need are loaded from disk to RAM, *everything* has to be read from the disk, which obviously is slower.

In short: for your use case, RAM_Booster is nothing more than snakeoil. The linux kernel is clever, and caches things it reads from the disk as long as possible in RAM; therefore, RAM_booster effectively just shifts the time for program startup into boot. To make things even worse, in many cases your RAM will be smaller than your OS'es complete disk usage, forcing your system to use swap space (ie. externalize data from RAM to disk just to make space free to actually *do* anything), negating any positive effect that prefetching might have.

In short: Unless you're really really really sure you know what your operating system does, don't try to force it to do something. Operating systems are smart.